# Laravel Database How to Setup Jobsheets With Jobs In Database

Tags: database, laravel, model, migration

I am looking for some advice please as to the best way to configure my laravel database.

The Software is for a Garage who fix cars etc. The Garage Admin will raise a new job on the system, then Engineers will be assigned the job.

Once an Engineer views the job he can open a job sheet. There are 3 different kinds of job sheets to choose.

The engineer will choose a job sheet (which is a checklist) and save the job sheet to the job. He then can open a different job sheet with a different set of questions (which is another checklist) and save that second job sheet to the same job. etc.

My issue is how to create in the database the job_sheet lists.

Do I create one migration with all questions from all sheets on one table with a job_sheet_type to categorise them?

Or do I create 3 separate tables in the database one for each sheet with a relation to the job_id?

I know this may seem very trivial, I am just trying to ensure I do this the best and most optimal way possible.

Please feel free to ask for further information and I can explain more. Thank you.

Comment: Create a sheets table which holds the name of the sheet. Create a tasks table which holds all of the checklist items. Create a many to many table to associate tasks with sheets. You can then create a task outcomes table which will hold the result of each task associated to a specific sheet.

Comment: Hi Savlon and thank you so much for your help. I like that idea, then it keeps everything separate and organised. Thank you so much for your help! I will try that.